# Getting error while creating new Angular Project

Tags: angular, angular-cli

> npm WARN deprecated istanbul-lib-hook@1.2.1: 1.2.0 should have been a

```
major version bump   
npm version: 5.5.1 node v8.9.3
```

Comment: Are you getting any npm errors? This is just a warning

Comment: update the npm version

Answer (score 3):

Update npm version

```
npm cache clean -f
npm install -g n
n stable
```

and then run 
`npm install`

Comment: Thanks, problem is solved.